# Why GitHub for Windows is seeing changes on this file?

Tags: git, github

I did auto-format my source files with eclipse, and did commit all on my repository using Eclipse.

Now I open GitHub desktop, and it shows all the files as "changes", but there's really no difference... It's just showing the same lines as deleted and added again.

I did commit one to illustrate:

https://github.com/tombrito/ArgoUML/commit/1ad47eab81fd0bf7d051dcfaea4f67a5edb2446a

What GitHub desktop for Windows is seeing as change here? In Eclipse there's nothing pending to commit.

Comment: Could it be newlines? CR before, CRLF after, or something like that? You may need to view in an appropriate editor to be sure. Check your  `core.autocrlf` setting to see what git is doing on commit.

Comment: cr-lf line endings are changed

Comment: What is the output of `type C:\ProgramData\Git\config`?  What version of Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the commit, the file has Windows (`0x0D 0x0A`) line endings. After the commit, the file has Unix (`0x0A`) line endings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too lazy to check it out, but from the commit I can see that every single line is changed, while there are no visible changes. So the changes are invisible. Specifically, the change is in the line separators: they're LF on Unix systems (including GitHub) and CRLF on Windows.

Now, many smart Git clients (Eclipse included) know about that and ignore the change—also handling transcoding on the fly. Some don't.